# What is wrong with my assignment overloading operator in c++? (Details included)

Tags: c++

Although I am following the guidelines for overloading the assignment operator, I am still not getting the correct output. My Implementation of the assignment operator in the header file looks like this:

```
const Poly &operator=(const Poly &rhs);
```

My Implementation of the assignment operator in the implementation file looks like this:

```
const Poly &Poly::operator=(const Poly &rhs) {

    //Set the coefficient of the rhs to lhs
    coef = rhs.coef;
    //Set the size of the rhs to lhs
    size = rhs.size;
    //Create a new polynomial with the same size and elements as the    original one
    polynomial = new int[rhs.size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        polynomial[i] = rhs.polynomial[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

The problem is when I try to do:

```
Poly a(-5, 7);
```

And then

```
Poly c = a;
```

I get a linker command failed problem. But when I do

```
Poly &c = a;
```

I don't get any errors and the final output is as expected. 
Any reason as to why this is happening?

Comment: Don't make the return value `const`.

Comment: Poly c = a; is not an assignment but a copy construction. This calls Poly::Poly(const Poly&).

Comment: Thank you kukyakya. I was missing the copy constructor. I have added it and now it works like charm. Thanks again.

Comment: Guessing, since it's not shown, that `polynomial` is a pointer to memory allocated on the free store? That assignment operator blows away the old pointer. It leaks memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see...

- `Poly a(-5, 7);` calls the constructor `Poly::Poly(int, int)`.
- `Poly c = a;` calls the copy constructor `Poly::Poly(const Poly &)`.
- `Poly &c = a;` doesn't call any constructor or method, but just creates a reference to `a`.

On the other hand...

- `Poly a(-5, 7); a = c;` Would call `operator=(const Poly &);`.

And just to note, users would expect that `operator=` will return `Poly &`, instead of `const Poly &`. Otherwise, code like `a = b = c;` would fail, when your users would expect it to succeed.